# How to persist an AbstractParty to the vault?

Tags: corda

What is the best way to persist an `AbstractParty` to the vault in Corda?
If it is a `Party`, I see in the cordapp-example that `party.toString()` does the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the Obligation CorDapp, you can do something like this:

```
val lenderString = (lender as? Party)?.name?.organisation ?: lender.owningKey.toBase58String()
```

Where lender is AbstractParty. If you are indeed dealing with an AbstractParty, you'll end up with the just owningKey.